# Is the element $(0,0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ a divisor of zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, real-numbers

(I'm assuming that $\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$)

In my assignment, I'm told to prove that exactly one of the following can be true for an element $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$

- $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$
- $(x,y,z)$ is invertible
- $(x,y,z)$ is a divisor of zero

I'm starting with the first. Given the definition of the operations on the ring $A=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ (we were given non-standard multiplication), the multiplicative identity is $(1,0,0)$.

There's no way that, given our definition, $(0,0,0)(0,0,0)^{-1}=(1,0,0)$ so it's not invertible.

However, my issue is with showing that it is not a zero divisor. Whenever I use algebra to find each component of another element in the ring $p$, such that $p\cdot(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)\cdot p= (0,0,0)$, this is always true. Any suggestion?

Comment: Zero divisor implies neither element is zero.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ... depending on author, of course, and yes, obviously in this person's course :)

Comment: If you do not tell us what "non-standard multiplication" you are using on $A$, then it is essentially impossible to know anything about tthe ring...

Answer (score 0):

By "[zero divisor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroDivisor.html)," your book probably means that $v \in \Bbb{R}^3$ is a zero divisor if and only if there exists some $a \in \Bbb{R}^3$ such that $a, v \neq 0$ and $av=\textbf{0}$. Therefore, $(0, 0, 0)$ is not a zero divisor because $(0, 0, 0) \neq \textbf{0}$ is false.

It is important to note that $(0, 0, 0)$ is intentionally excluded from the definition of zero divisor because some mathematicians think that this is a more useful definition of zero divisor. This way, we can talk about rings without zero divisors called [integral domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain), where if $av=\textbf{0}$, then either $a=\textbf{0}$ or $v=\textbf{0}$. This would be rings like $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^3$ where you can't get $\textbf{0}$ by multiplying two non-zero elements.

Thus, because of the definition of zero divisor used in your book, $(0, 0, 0)$ is not a zero divisor.

Comment: The very link you include subscribes to the definition that allows zero to be a zero divisor. It is probably not the case that "mathematicians prefer" the restricted definition, although some particular specialization might.

Comment: It is the case that mathematicians prefer the restricted definition, and I'm going to edit wiki tomorrow. The terminology "... Without zero divisors" can be found referring to rings in every major textbook, but directly implies that $0$ is not a zero divisor.

Comment: @rschwieb I've changed the link to Wolfram Alpha rather than Wikipedia to make clear that $0$ is not a zero divisor and I've added the word "most" before "mathematicians" to imply that this is not a consensus. Sorry about the ambiguity. I am quite sure that $0$ being excluded is preferred, however, because I've almost always (not always, but almost always) seen it defined this way.

Comment: Dear @NobleMushtak : I don't even know if "most" is an appropriate qualifier. I'm not sure such clairvoyance is necessary, though. You might really be best off saying "some authors define it this way, and it is clear that your author is one of those." Regards.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually have zero divisors depending on how multiplication is defined. If addition is point-wise, then (1,0,1)(0,1,0)=(0,0,0).
You said you were given non-standard multiplication. Was it defined for you?

Comment: This person specifically wants to show that $(0, 0, 0)$ is not a zero divisor which is false for all rings if you exclude $\textbf{0}$ from the definition of zero divisor.